# My header is not showing up on my webpage as well as my logo

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, controller

I am not sure what the issue is, I have no syntax errors but I should have a navigation bar at the top of my screen but it is not showing up. Is there something in the syntax I need to change? Did I miss something in my default template file as well? My webpage shows up fine but I am just missing my image and navigation bar.

common.html file

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    <div th:fragment="header">
        <h1>Welcome to my CST-339 Spring Boot Activity Application</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" data-target="navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">GCU</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.gcu.edu" target="_blank">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.lopeshops.edu" target="_blank">Shop</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.news.edu" target="_blank">News and Events</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/">Start Page</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <h2 th:text="${title}">Default Message Text</h2><br />
    <img th:src="@{/static/images/gcu-logo.jpg}" /><br /><br />
<div th:fragment="footer">
    <h5 style="color:purple; text-align: center; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;">Copyright 2020 Grand Canyon University</h5>  
</div>
</html>
```

defaultTemplate.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title> CST-339 Spring Boot Activity Application</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css.bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css.bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/css/responsive.dataTables.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">.bs-example {margin: 20px; }</style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <div th:replace="~{layouts/common :: header}">My Header</div>
            <section layout:fragment="content">
                <p>My Body Contents</p>
            </section>
            <div th:replace="~{layouts/common :: footer}">My Footer</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your logo is in static/images folder, to show it

Replace

```
<img th:src="@{/static/images/gcu-logo.jpg}" /><br
```

With

```
<img th:src="@{images/gcu-logo.jpg}" /><br
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of navigation bar

First css links are not accessible instead of

```
 https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css.bootstrap.min.css
 https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css.bootstrap-theme.min.css
```

should be

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
```

Second: when setting style `class` you are missing `th` i.e. should be `th:class="class-name"` for single class or `th:classappend="|class1 class2 class3|"` for multiple classes

Third: to enable nav button to show menus when they are collapsed, `data-target` value should be `.navbar-collapse`  instead of `navbarCollapse`

The following complete sample loads collapsible nav bar

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title> CST-339 Spring Boot Activity Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/css/responsive.dataTables.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">.bs-example {margin: 20px; }</style>
</head>

<body>
    <!--    <div th:fragment="header">-->
    <h1>Welcome to my CST-339 Spring Boot Activity Application</h1>
    <!--    </div>-->
    <div th:class="bs-example">
        <nav th:classappend="|navbar navbar-default|">
            <div th:class="navbar-header">
                <button th:type="button" th:data-target=".navbar-collapse" th:data-toggle="collapse" th:class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span th:class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span th:class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span th:class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span th:class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" th:class="navbar-brand">GCU</a>
            </div>

            <div id="navbarCollapse" th:classappend="|collapse navbar-collapse|">
                <ul th:classappend="|nav navbar-nav|">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.gcu.edu" target="_blank">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.lopeshops.edu" target="_blank">Shop</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.news.edu" target="_blank">News and Events</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul th:classappend="|nav navbar-nav navbar-right|">
                    <li><a href="/">Start Page</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```