# Error accessing an image in Thymeleaf + SpringBoot

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have this template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'>
    <title>jui</title>
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Menu -->
    <link id="themeLink" th:href="@{/css/mystic-rivers.css}"  rel="stylesheet" />

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">


</head>
<body bgcolor="#f0f0f0">
<header>
    <img th:src="@{/images/137364472_padded_logo.png}"  alt="mystic-rivers" class="logo"/>
    <!-- Other header content goes here -->
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

and this error when accessing `https://www.mystic-rivers.com/images/137364472_padded_logo-2.png`:

```
22:02:35.765 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR o.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log 175 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.transferTo(InputStream.java:782)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeContent(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:138)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:225)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:593)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

same happens when accessing the CSS

Comment: Might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76640004/my-header-is-not-showing-up-on-my-webpage-as-well-as-my-logo/76770679#76770679)

Comment: The error in your stack trace is `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back` -- that really doesn't have anything to do with the template here..?

Comment: I've spotted WsFilter filter in that stack-trace, which the Tomcat docs [says](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/server/WsFilter.html) is for WebSockets.

The exception and the template seem unrelated. Somewhere in your codebase you have some WebSocket related code, so look for that. Otherwise check that the version of Tomcat you're using doesn't have a WebSockets related bug.

Comment: @Nuñito Calzada , does this happen when you request `https://www.mystic-rivers.com/images/137364472_padded_logo-2.png` directly from a browser address bar? Does the same thing happen when you request `https://www.mystic-rivers.com/css/mystic-rivers.css`? What version of JDK and Spring Boot are you running?

Comment: Please conduct a thorough examination of your project dependencies, ensure the integrity of the provided ZIP file, and provide detailed information about the codebase you are currently working on. Kindly share any additional relevant code as the error does not appear to originate from the template. This will assist us in diagnosing and resolving the issue more effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibilities:

1. If the image exists: Make sure that the image file 137364472_padded_logo.png exists in the correct location within your project's resources or web directory.
2. Image Format: Ensure that the image file is in a supported format (e.g., PNG, JPEG, GIF) and is not corrupted.
3. "invalid distance too far back":
   suggests a problem with data compression. Check if there's any compression or middleware (e.g., GZIP) applied to your web server's response that might be causing this issue.

Reference: [java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back while decompressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151669/java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-distance-too-far-back-while-decompressing)

Verify the three possibilities, let see what will happen.